# Call C/C++ code from Python

Tags: python, c, matlab, mex

I am currently working on a project to import a Matlab program to python for integration into ImageJ as a plugin. The program contains Mex files and the source code was written in C++. Is there a way to call the C++ functions without having to rewrite them in python. Thanks!!!

Comment: How exactly do you want to call the C-functions? Which functions would these be? Are they available as Python-functions?

Comment: @ThePathan: You won't be able to call MEX functions directly from Python, I think. You'd need to have implementations of all the MATLAB MEX API functions, which seems impossible unless you are using MATLAB.

Comment: ...see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848790/embed-a-function-from-a-matlab-mex-file-directly-in-python) for more details.

Comment: More details can be found here: [Calling C/C++ from python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can build your program as a shared library, then you can use the `ctypes` foreign-function interface to call your functions.

This is often less work (and less complex) than wrapping the functions with Cython or writing your own C-API extension, but it is also more limited in what you can do. Therefore, I recommend starting with `ctypes`, and moving up to Cython if you find that `ctypes` doesn't suit your needs.

However, for simple libraries, `ctypes` will do just fine (I use it a lot).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! Searching around, it seems ctypes is the easiest way to start off. Also, I can import **ctypes** from within the ImageJ environment, which is important for my project (The project is to convert the Matlab program into an imageJ plugin). However, I have never built anything as a  shared library. I may be asking you for help, if it gets too complicated. But Thanks for the help. It is very appreciated.

Comment: @ThePathan: Don't forget to select your favorite answer by marking the **✓** to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You would need to wrap those C functions into python C extensions, through the [Python C-API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/), for them to be callable from python; however, i can tell you from experience that the task can be a headache if you don't know what you're doing.

I would recommend checking out [cython](http://docs.cython.org/). It makes writing C extensions as easy as writing python code!